# Comine various interfaces and props in React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having an interface like this. This represents the "base button".

```
export interface ButtonProps {
    backgroundColor?: Colors,
    children?: React.ReactNode | JSX.Element,
    style?: CSSProperties,
    disabled?: boolean,
    onClick?: () => void,
}
```

I now want to build ontop of that a "Text Button", a Button containing text.

```
interface TextButtonProps {
    buttonProps?: ButtonProps,
    textColor?: Colors,
}
```

I knwo want to extract the property `backgroundColor` from `ButtonProps`, using it in `<TextButton />`

```
const TextButton = ({
                        backgroundColor,
                        textColor = 'black',
                        textProps,
                        ...buttonProps,
                    }: TextButtonProps) => {
    return (
        ...
    )
```

Is there a way to make `backgroundColor` available to `<TextButton />`, without explicitly naming it again in the `TextButtonProps`? I could do it like this

```
interface TextButtonProps {
    backgroundColor?: Colors,
    buttonProps?: ButtonProps,
    textColor?: Colors,
}
```

But I would repeat myself, because `ButtonProps` contains already `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your types as-is and pass the properties down to `Button`:

```
const TextButton: React.FC<TextButtonProps> = ({ textColor, buttonProps }) => (
  <Button {...buttonProps}>
    <Text color={textColor}>...</Text>
  </Text>
);
```

If you need to use, for example, `ButtonProps.backgroundColor` inside `<TextButton>` then you'd need to write something like this `<Text foreground={textColor} background={buttonProps?.backgroundColor}>`. I, personally, find `TextButtonProps.buttonProps` a bit confusing: think about the caller:

```
<TextButton textColor="red" buttonProps={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}>
  Click me
</TextButton>
```

Truly confusing.

As a note: you can pick a property from a type:

```
interface TextButtonProps extends Pick<ButtonProps, "backgroundColor"> {
}
```

But it's NOT what I'd do here, I'd simply extend the `ButtonProps` interface with the additional properties:

```
interface TextButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  textColor?: Colors;
}
```

Your component will then be:

```
const TextButton: React.FC<TextButtonProps> = ({ children, textColor, ...buttonProps }) => (
  <Button {...buttonProps}>
    <Text color={textColor}>{children}</Text>
  </Text>
);
```

---

An extra note: you do not need to declare `children` if you use `React.FC` (I strongly suggest to always do it). Note that types for React 18 change a bit so you might need to use `React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps>>`.
Another one: remember that `type T = { ... } & V` is NOT the same as `interface T extends V { ... }` (even if, in most cases, you probably do not care about the difference).

Comment: How would you make `backgroundColor` available to the caller of `<TextButton />` then? I am unsure how to do it, that is why I came up this `buttonProps={{backgroundColor...}}` "solution", but I wanna rewrite it because its way to confusing.

Comment: See last example, if you extend the interface then it's simply `<TextButton textColor="red" backgroundColor="green">Click me</TextButton>`

Comment: Ah, alright. Perfect, thanks. I am very new to TypeScript. In VanillaJS, I know how to do it.

Comment: Yet another Questions: Is there a way to extend `TextButtonProps` by two interfaces, let's say `ButtonProps` and `TextProps` and then do something like `const TextButton: React.FC<TextButtonProps> = ({ children, textColor, ...buttonProps, ...textProps }) => (
  <Button {...buttonProps}>
    <Text color={textColor} {...textProps}>{children}</Text>
  </Text>
);` This, `interface TextButtonProps extends ButtonProps, TextProps` is not working.

Comment: You can extend two interfaces (like `TextButtonProps extends ButtonProps, TextProps` - assuming properties are _compatible_) but you can't write `..buttonProps, ...textProps`, for that you'll need to be explicit and to extract each one from one of the two. Unfortunately types are visible only at compile-time so you won't be able to "magically" copy properties from T1 excluding those from T2. It's an entirely different approach but if you have to do it very often and you have more than a few properties then you might consider a library like `joy` or `yup`

Comment: errata: `joi`. there are also other good libraries out there. with them you can create the types (for TS) and also have the metadata you need at runtime (but they'll add another level of complexity so I'd use them only if really needed)

Comment: Damn... Alright, then I'll extract them. Its only in one component (so far), but that problem might occur in every "composed" component like `<IconButton />` <- Props for `<Icon />` and `<Button/>` or `<TextButton />` which could consist of `<Button />` and `<Text />`.

Comment: yeah, that'll happen often if you're building some UI component library. Some libs use properties because of that (like `interface TextButtonProps { buttonProps?: ButtonProps; textProps?: TextProps }`) also because of this but it makes the calling point a bit messy (IMHO). If possible what I'd like to do to mitigate this is to make the higher level components highly opinionated: use it as-is (without customisations) or build your own. It could also have the advantage of streamlining the UI (which is a benefit on itself if you're writing a generic unopinionated open source component library)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a type that has additional properties, you can use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```js
type TextButtonProps = ButtonProps & {
    textColor?: Colors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this without creating an extra type definition:

**TextButtonProps & TextButtonProps[keyof TextButtonProps]**  as type, it should take the nested types too

```
const TextButton = ({
      backgroundColor,
      textColor = 'black',
      textProps,
      ...buttonProps,
}: TextButtonProps & TextButtonProps[keyof TextButtonProps] ) => {
```